# How to create PDF only after Google Apps Script replaceText() is done?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a basic templating system using Google Apps Script.

1. Loop over each template and duplicate it.
2. Call `replaceText(TAG, REPLACEMENT_STRING)` on the copy.
3. Generate a PDF.

The problem is that my PDF is generated before `replaceText` happens and the PDF still contains my tags.

Current code looks like this:

```
doc.getBody.replaceText("{{tag1}}", "Hello World");
createPDF(doc);
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, how about putting `doc.saveAndClose()` before the line of `createPDF(doc);`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveandclose)

Comment: Indeed, it solved the problem. Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Created PDF does not reflect changes made to the original document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902910/created-pdf-does-not-reflect-changes-made-to-the-original-document)