# .getBlob().as('application/pdf') is converting the wrong file even though the file id is correct

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to make a copy of a basic Google doc template, replace text, append a table and a paragraph then convert the copy of the doc to a pdf file and attach it to an email.

I have been able to create a copy of the Google doc and make the changes I want.

My problem is when I use .getBlob().as('application/pdf'), it converts the original template into a pdf instead of the copy that has changes in it.

I have checked the file Ids and they are correct so I don't know how this is happening.

```
function convertToPdf(){
    var template = DriveApp.getFileById('1S5-fujBacEZmsCwMy5haxjRXwROJkQNfeEMim3YSk9s');
    var dstFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1-yW6jKPC1BctT7pGo1dQSbhvN3wlhxqP');
    var copy = DriveApp.getFileById(template.getId()).makeCopy(`Invoice for ${client_name}`,dstFolder);
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

var tableData = header.concat(services).map(row => row.splice(1,4));
    var replacetxt2 = doc.getBody().replaceText('{Client Name}',client_name);
    var table = doc.getBody().appendTable(tableData);
    var tableHeader = table.getRow(0);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      tableHeader.getCell(i).setBackgroundColor('#FFC0CB')
    }
    tableHeader.editAsText().setBold(true).setForegroundColor('#000000');
    const sumtotal = doc.getBody().appendParagraph('$'+sum);



    var email = GmailApp.sendEmail('email@gmail.com', `Invoice for ${client_name}`, 'Your invoice as requested',
      {
        attachments: [doc.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf')]
      })

    
  }
```

Comment: In your script, please put `doc.saveAndClose()` just after the line of `const sumtotal = doc.getBody().appendParagraph('$'+sum);` and test it again. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveandclose) If this was the solution to your issue, I will flag your question as the duplicated question of https://stackoverflow.com/q/40902910 .

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your reply, I flagged your question as a duplicated question.