# Google Script not creating PDF from updated copy, using template instead

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Im fumbling through a script that fills in  Google Docs template, creates a new copy, converts that copy to PDF, then finally deletes the docs copy.

I have the steps working that creates, updates, coverts, deletes.  My problem is that when the PDF is created, its just creating a PDF of the template, not the updated copy of the template.

Here is the script (I apologize I cant recall the source where I found the original script)

```
function createDocs(spreadsheetData) {
  
  // Log starting createDocs Function
  logEvent('Starting createDocs Function');
  
  
  // separate out data from name:value pair array
  var spreadsheet = spreadsheetData['spreadsheet'];
  var ss = spreadsheet.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = spreadsheetData['dataSheet'];
  var destinationFolderId = spreadsheetData['destinationFolderId'];
  var templateFileId = spreadsheetData['templateFileId'];
  var data = spreadsheetData['data'];
  
  
  
  try {
    // try getting the Folder and then set variable as true if successful
    var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
    var gotDestinationFolder = true;
  }
  catch(e) {
    // if failed set variable as false and Log
    var gotDestinationFolder = false;
    logEvent('Failed to get destinationFolder with error: ' + e);
  }
  
  
  // only proceed if got destination Drive Folder
  if (gotDestinationFolder) {
    
    try {
      // try getting the Template File and then set variable as true if successful
      var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(templateFileId);
      var gotTemplateFile = true;
    }
    catch(e) {
      var gotTemplateFile = false;
      logEvent('Failed to get templateFile with error: ' + e);
    }
    
  }
  else {
    // do nothing
  }
  
  
  // only proceed if got Template File also
  if (gotTemplateFile) {
    
    
    // loop through each row of data and create new Doc ******************************
    var dataLength = data.length;
    for (var i=1; i<dataLength; i++) {
      
      // extract values from array of data
      var attendee = data[i][0];
      var timeStamp = data[i][1];
      var merchant = data[i][2];
      var amount = data[i][3];
      var category = data[i][4];
      var derivedDescription = data[i][6];
      var reportTitle = data [i][11];
      var expenseId = data [i][13];

      
      // create name for new File
      var newFileName = reportTitle + ': ' + expenseId;
      
      // make copy of Template File and place in destination Drive Folder
      var newFile = templateFile.makeCopy(newFileName, destinationFolder);
      
      // get ID and Url of new File
      var newFileID = newFile.getId();
      var newFileUrl = newFile.getUrl();
      
      
      try {
        // try opening the new File, get its Body and then set variable as true if successful
        var newFileBody = DocumentApp.openById(newFileID).getBody();
        var openNewFile = true;
      }
      catch(e) {
        // if failed set variable as false and Log
        var openNewFile = false;
        logEvent('Failed to open newFileBody with error: ' + e);
      }
      
      
      // only proceed if got Body of new File
      if (openNewFile) {
        
        // replace tags with data from sheet
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<attendee>>', attendee);
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<merchant>>', merchant);
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<timeStamp>>', timeStamp);
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<amount>>', amount);
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<category>>', category);
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<derivedDescription>>', derivedDescription);
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<reportTitle>>', reportTitle);
        newFileBody.replaceText('<<expenseId>>', expenseId);
        ss.toast('Text Replaced','Doc Creation Status',3);
        

        
        


        // get file content as PDF blob

        var file = DriveApp.getFileById(newFileID);
        var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
        var pdfBlob = file.getAs('application/pdf');

        // create new PDF file in Google Drive folder
        folder.createFile(pdfBlob);
        // delete original Google Doc file
        file.setTrashed(true);


        
        // paste a hyperlink to new File in spreadsheet
        //var newFileLink = '=HYPERLINK("' + newFileUrl + '","' + newFileName + '")';
        //dataSheet.getRange(i+1, 5).setFormula(newFileLink);
        
        
        // refresh spreadsheet to links appear as soon as added
        //spreadsheet.flush();

        
        
        // display Toast notification to confirm row complete
        //ss.toast('Row ' + (i+1) + ': ' + newFileName, 'Completed Doc',3);
      }
      else {
        // do nothing
      }
      
    }
    // loop through each row of data and create new Doc ******************************
    
    
  }
  else {
    // do nothing
  }
  




  
  // display Toast notification to inform end of the script
  ss.toast('Script has now ended', 'End');
  
  
  // Log end of the script
  logEvent('Script has ended');
  
  
}
```

I thought I could try the saveAndClose method -but it doesn't seem that I understand how to call it properly.  My idea was that perhaps the code is not using the updated version of the file, or that the changes weren't being written to the file before the PDF code was being run.

Comment: From your current issue, I'm worried that the template document might not be saved. So, in your showing script, please add `DocumentApp.openById(newFileID).saveAndClose()` just before the line of `var file = DriveApp.getFileById(newFileID);` and test it again. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40902910

Comment: This worked!  I was really struggling trying to call saveAndClose method.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resoleved. Thank you, too.