# Can't get google sheets to display the selected range while script is still running

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want the sheet displayed to scroll down to a range while a script is still running.
This would let me answer a ui.alert() whilst being able to check the data from the sheet displayed in the background.

Bellow are the scripts I have tried :

```
function Test() {
  var document = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var sheet = document.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(100, 1); // The range I want to be displayed

  sheet.setActiveRange(range); // First attempt => works perfectly, but late
  // SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range); => attempt 2
  // sheet.setActiveSelection(range); => attempt 3

  var query = ui.alert("Scroll display" + "The selected cell is displayed", ui.ButtonSet.OK);
}
```

All the scripts, I have tried works perfectly, i.e., scroll to the wanted (selected) range once the script is finished, but none manage to do it while it is still running, before the `ui.alert()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Script is clearing data too early, does anyone know why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753860/script-is-clearing-data-too-early-does-anyone-know-why)

Comment: Thanks a lot, the command I was missing was SpreadsheetApp.flush(), as indicated in the other post. Will post an answer of the correct code.

Answer (score 1):

The command needed is : SpreadsheetApp.flush() (thx TheMaster).

```
function Test() {
  var document = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var sheet = document.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(100, 1 ); // The range I want to be displayed

  sheet.setActiveRange(range);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var query = ui.alert("Display" + "The cell (100,1) is displayed", ui.ButtonSet.OK);
}
```